# Is there a counterexample to "For all integers $a,b, d$, if $d\mid(3a+2b)$ and $d\mid(2a+b)$, then $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$."

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I've tried to solve this problem, but I keep getting stuck at the end.

Assume $a, b$ , and d are integers and $d$ $\neq$ 0.

> $3a+2b = dm,\,\,\,$ for some integer $m$.
>
> $2a+b = dn,\,\,\,$ for some integer $n$.
>
> $3a+2b - 2a - b = dm - dn$.
>
> $a + b = d(m-n)$.

That's where I'm stuck now, because $a=d(m-n)-b or b=d(m-n)-a$ doesn't prove $d\mid a$ or $d\mid b$, unless I'm missing something or took a wrong turn somewhere.

Please help me, and thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that replied, you were all very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
3a+2b=dm, \quad 2(2a+b)=2dn\Longrightarrow a=d(2n-m),\quad
$$
and
$$
2(3a+2b)=2dm, \quad 3(2a+b)=3dn\Longrightarrow b=d(2m-3n).
$$

Answer (score 3):

By the hypothesis we have

$$d|(3a+2b)-(2a+b)\iff d|a+b$$
hence

$$d|(2a+b)-(a+b)\iff d|a$$
and
$$d|(2a+b)-2(a+b)\iff d|-b\iff d|b$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no counterexample:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
6a + 4b = 2md \\
6a + 3b = 3nd \\
b = (2m-3n)d \rightarrow d|b \\
6a + (8m-12n)d = 2md \\
6a = (-6m -12n) d \\
a = (-2m+3n)d \rightarrow d|a
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis, $m=\frac{3a+2b}d$ and $n=\frac{2a+b}d$ are integers. Solving the linear equations
$$3(\frac ad)+2(\frac bd)=m$$
$$2(\frac ad)+(\frac bd)=n$$
for $\frac ad$ and $\frac bd$, we get $\frac ad=2n-m\in\mathbb Z$ and $\frac bd=2m-3n\in\mathbb Z$.